# Authorize does not work in mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin

I created a mvc 5 web application that I like to secure using owin, I use the following code in my startup.cs file which is located in the root of the web application..

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureAuth(app);
}


public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Login/Index"),
        CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest
    });
}
```

But even if I ad this in my home controller, I can still access it without successfully login?!

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you using WindowsAuthentication? If so, then you are automatically authorized

Comment: I have not defined anything like that in my web.config. But I do run the site through visual studio, am I using windowsauthentication automatically then?

Comment: When you start a new project with visual studio there is a wizard asking for authentication. You can choose between "No Authentication", "Individual User Accounts", "Work and School Accounts" and "Windows Authentication". Which one did you choose?

Comment: I created an empty project with references to mvc, when one does that it is automatically "no authentication".

Comment: Sorry i was not able to reproduce this on my machine. Try a new project and under Authentication choose "Individual User Accounts". Afterwards you can compare your differences... Sorry for no better idea.

Comment: do you have `Startup.cs` file? in there you should have something like `[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(MyProjectName.Startup))]`. Do you have it?

Comment: Yes that part is there..

Comment: I got it to work by adding Filterconfig.cs in my App_Start folder that look like this...

    public class FilterConfig
    {

        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
            filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
        }

    }

And in global.asax Application_Start I added this..

FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);